# java fifo queue that allows pushing back?

Tags: java, data-structures, nio

is there a fifo queue implementation that provides for replacing the head element after a peek?

i'd like to use this to push a partially written buffer back onto the queue after a partial write onto a network connection (when using java nio selector).

this would be a bit cleaner than sticking the partially written buffer as an attachment on the selection key,  but if there's no convenient implementation available I'll have to use that.

Comment: Doesn't peek just check the first element and not remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [Deque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) which allows you to add to the start or the end.

However, if you have a partial write and your buffers are not huge, you could have a slow consumer and you might consider a different action such as closing the connection.

Answer (score -1):

After a peek the head element is undisturbed, so your question doesn't make sense. Just peek, try the write, and if there is nothing left *then* remove the buffer from the queue.

Comment: please re-read the post.  the point is if the write was not complete, I would want to replace the head of the queue with the remaining data.  thanks.

Comment: @eqbridges Please re-read the answer. The point is that (a) you haven't removed anything from the queue in the first place, so there is nothing to replace, and (b) it is simpler only to remove it after you've finished with it rather than remove it and then start an Internet forum search for how to get it back there.